# How to define format when using pandas to_datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to plot RESULT vs TIME based on a `testresult.csv` file that has following format, and I have trouble to get the TIME column's datatype defined properly.

```
TIME,RESULT  
03/24/2016 12:27:11 AM,2  
03/24/2016 12:28:41 AM,76  
03/24/2016 12:37:23 AM,19  
03/24/2016 12:38:44 AM,68  
03/24/2016 12:42:02 AM,44  
...
```

To read the csv file, this is the code I wrote:
`raw_df = pd.read_csv('testresult.csv', index_col=None, parse_dates=['TIME'], infer_datetime_format=True)`
This code works, but it is extremely slow, and I assume that the `infer_datetime_format` takes time. So I tried to read in the csv by default first, and then convert the object dtype 'TIME' to datetime dtype by using `to_datetime()`, and I hope by defining the format, it might expedite the speed.

```
raw_df =  pd.read_csv('testresult.csv')
raw_df.loc['NEWTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(raw_df['TIME'], format='%m/%d%Y %-I%M%S %p')
```

This code complained error:

> `"ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%m/%d%Y %-I%M%S %p'"`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The format you are passing is invalid. The dash between the `%` and the `I` is not supposed to be there.

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

This will convert your `TIME` column to a datetime.

---

Alternatively, you can adjust your `read_csv` call to do this:

```
pd.read_csv('testresult.csv', parse_dates=['TIME'], 
    date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

Again, this uses the appropriate format with out the extra `-`, but it also passes in the format to the [`date_parser`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter instead of having pandas attempt to guess it with the `infer_datetime_format` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, Andy.  I guess I also carelessly missed ":" between hour, minute and second, that's why even I tried %I, it still failed. The time in my table does have some cases with none zero-padding hour format "03/24/2016 1:08:19 AM", and based on Python's strftime format (see this http://strftime.org/ list), it should use '%-I'. Do you know why pandas is not consistent with this?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
In [69]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=[0],
                          date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
                 TIME  RESULT
0 2016-03-24 00:27:11       2
1 2016-03-24 00:28:41      76
2 2016-03-24 00:37:23      19
3 2016-03-24 00:38:44      68
4 2016-03-24 00:42:02      44
```