# Date formatting to month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to change the format of "Date" column from 10/15/2019 to m/d/y format.

```
tax['AsOfdate']= pd.to_datetime(tax['date'])
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define format when use pandas to\_datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848514/how-to-define-format-when-use-pandas-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

like this, and here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```py
tax['AsOfdate']= pd.to_datetime(tax['date'], format="%m/%d/%Y" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with today's date formatting:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
new_format = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
print(today, new_format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `to_datetime` function accepts a format command which accepts strftime notation.

Pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Strftime docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

m/d/y notation would be:

```
tax['AsOfdate']= pd.to_datetime(tax['date'], format='%m/%d/%y)
```

Assuming you want everything zero padded with two digits like 01/01/19 for January first 2019. If you need something else, the strftime formatting link shows all the codes that let you choose padding or not, four-digit year or two-digit, and so on.