# Python Azure SDK - Incorrect datetime format inferred when reading tabular data from blobstore with from_delimited_files()

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using the Azure Python SDK to read a tabular dataset from a Blob Store as follows:

```py
df = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path=[DataPath(ds, blobstore_dir + 'tabular_data.csv')],
                                          separator=',', header=True)
```

The data has four datetime columns, one of the columns reads in with no problem because there are instances where the month-day order is not ambiguous, but the other three are being inferred incorrectly as "month-day" instead of "day-month".

When reading in the data I get the following warning:

> UserWarning: Ambiguous datetime formats inferred for columns ['Period Start', 'Period End', 'Extracted At'] are resolved as "month-day". Desired format can be specified by `set_column_types`.

I have attempted to set the column types as below, and have tried a few different formats but all I end up with is NULL in place of all the values.

```
df = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(
        path=[DataPath(ds, blobstore_dir + 'tabular_data.csv')], separator=',', header=True,
        set_column_types={'Period Start': DataType.to_datetime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),
                          'Period End': DataType.to_datetime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),
                          'Extracted At': DataType.to_datetime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")})
```

The documentation for `from_delimited_files()` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.tabulardatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#from-delimited-files-path--validate-true--include-path-false--infer-column-types-true--set-column-types-none--separator------header-true--partition-format-none--support-multi-line-false--empty-as-string-false--encoding--utf8--)

Can anyone tell me how to force `from_delimited_files()` to resolve the ambiguous datetimes as day-month or tell me how to use `set_column_types` correctly? I've worked around it temporarily by inserting a dummy row with a non-ambiguous datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can Import **Pandas** and use to `date_parser` and **to_datetime** with the format you can convert the date-time with the respective format.

```
date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

Reading from file

```
pd.read_csv('testresult.csv', parse_dates=['TIME'], 
    date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

It also passes in the format to the [`date_parser`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter instead of having pandas attempt to guess it with the `infer_datetime_format` parameter.

Refer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36849011/15997690)