# I have a dataframe with a date column in the following format: 20130526T150000. How do you change this column to datetime 2013-05-26 15:00:00?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

Does anyone know how to change 20130526T150000 to datetime format?

Comment: this shiuld not be 2013-05-26 15:00:00??

Comment: I edited it the questions my bad

Answer (score -1):

One note: the 'T' is usefull. Use [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) directly, the T is actually usefull as it denotes the iso format and will help not confuse for some locales (some countries have the month first, then the day, others the oposite - iso goes from most significant to less: year, month, day)...

```
pd.to_datetime("20130526T150000")

Timestamp('2013-05-26 15:00:00')
```

If you want to be more explicit, specify [the format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
pd.to_datetime("20130526T150000", format=...)
```

However, this might be a duplicate: [How to define format when using pandas to_datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848514/how-to-define-format-when-using-pandas-to-datetime) ... For best results, if you are doing a conversion of a column, use [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime/42773096#42773096)

Comment: When i try that it comes up with a parsing error - ParserError: month must be in 1..12: 20121711T150000

Comment: I have noticed, this actually should not be happening... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73688212/pandas-to-datetime-format-bug btw, what pandas version do you use?

Comment: (use e.g. `print (pd.__version__)` ... Also, python version?)